# Optimize python csv processing into parent and EAV child table

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, optimization, query-optimization

There's been several similar questions around online for processing large csv files into multiple postgresql tables with python. However, none seem to address a couple concerns around optimizing database reads/writes and system memory/processing.

Say I have a row of product data that looks like this:

name,sku,datetime,decimal,decimal,decimal,decimal,decimal,decimal

Where the name and sku are stored in one table (parent), then each decimal field is stored in a child EAV table that essentially contains the decimal, parent_id, and datetime.

Let's say I have 20000 of these rows in a csv file, so I end up chunking them up. Right now, I take chunks of 2000 of these rows and loop line by line. Each iteration checks to see if the product exists and creates it if not, retrieving the parent_id. Then, I have a large list of insert statements generated for the child table with the decimal values. If the user has selected to only overwrite non-modified decimal values, then this also checks each individual decimal value to see if it has been modified before adding to the insert list.

In this example, if I had the worst case scenario, I'd end up doing 160,000 database reads and anywhere from 10-20010 writes. I'd also be storing up to 12000 insert statements in a list in memory for each chunk (however, this would only be one list, so that part isn't as bad).

My main question is:

- How can I optimize this to be faster, use less database operations (since this also affects network traffic), and use less processing and memory? I'd also rather have the processing speed to be slower if it could save on the other two optimizations, as those ones cost more money when translated to server/database processing pricing in something like AWS.

Some sub questions are:

- Is there a way I can combine all the product read/writes and replace them in the file before doing the decimals?
- Should I be doing a smaller chunk size to help with memory?
- Should I be utilizing threads or keeping it linear?
- Could I have it build a more efficient sql query that does the product create if not exists and referencing inline, thus moving some of the processing into sql rather than python?
- Could I optimize the child insert statements to do something better than thousands of INSERT INTO statements?

Comment: Post data and tables definitions.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto The data and table definitions are arbitrary - I outlined all the relevant info about the tables above. Namely a parent table in this case would have id, name, and sku columns, and the child table would have a FK to the parent id, a decimal, and a datetime column. My actual code and tables are much more complex, so this simplifies it immensely.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? There may be some database features that simplify the overall logic (e.g., `insert ... on conflict`, which is new in 9.5)

Comment: @bimsapi I'm on 9.6, so could utilize something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fun question, but one that's hard to answer precisely, since there are many
variables defining the best solution that may or may not apply.

Below is one approach, based on the following assumptions -

- You don't need the database code to be portable.
- The csv is structured with a header, or at the least the attribute names are
  known and fixed.
- The sku (or name/sku combo) in product table have unique constraints.
- Likewise, the EAV table has a unique constraint on `product_id`, and
  `attr_name`

  - Corollary - you didn't specify, but I also assume that the EAV table has a field
    for the attribute name.

The process boils down to -

- Load the data into the database by the fastest path possible
- Unpivot the csv from a tabular structure to EAV structure during or after the load
- "Upsert" the resulting records - update if present, insert otherwise.

### Approach -

All that background, given a similar problem, here is the approach I would take.

- Create temp tables mirroring the final destination, but without pks, types, or constraints

  - The temp tables will get deleted when the database session ends
- Load the .csv straight into the temp tables in a single pass; two SQL executions per row

  - One for product
  - One for the EAV, using the 'multi-value' insert - `insert into tmp_eav (sku, attr_name, attr_value) values (%s, %s), (%s, %s)...`.
  - `psycopg2` has a custom method to do this for you: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values
- Select from tmp tables to upsert into final tables, using a statement like `insert into product (name, sku) select name, sku from tmp_product on conflict (sku) do nothing`

  - This requires PostgreSQL 9.5+.
  - For the user-selectable requirement to optionally update fields based on the csv, you can change `do nothing` to `do update set col = excluded.col`. `excluded` is the input row that conflicted

### Alternative approach -

- Create the temp table based on the structure of the csv (assumes you have
  have enough metadata to do this on each run *or* that the csv structure is
  fixed and can be consistently translated to a table)
- Load the csv into the database using the COPY command (supported in psycopg2
  via the `cursor.copy_from` method, passing in the csv as a file object).
  This will be faster than anything you write in Python

  - Caveat: this works if the csv is very dependable (same number of cols on
    every row) *and* the temp table is very lax w/ nulls, all strings w/ no
    type coercion.
- You can 'unpivot' the csv rows with a `union all` query that combines a
  select for each column to row transpose. The 6 decimals in your example 
  should be manageable.

For example:

```
select sku, 'foo' as attr_name, foo as attr_value from tmp_csv union all
select sku, 'bar' as attr_name, bar as attr_value from tmp_csv union all
...
order by sku;
```

This solution hits a couple of the things you were you interested in:

- Python application memory remains flat
- Network I/O is limited to what it takes to get the .csv into the db and issue
  the right follow up sql statements

A little general advice to close out -

- Optimal and "good enough" are almost never the same thing
- Optimal is only required under very specific situations
- So, aim for "good enough", but be precise about what "good enough" means -
  i.e., pick one or two measures
- Iterate, solving for one variable at a time. In my experience, the first hurdle (say, "end to end processing time less than
  X seconds") is often sufficient.

Comment: This looks great and gives me a good direction to refactor. I am leaning toward the second approach because the files will be forced to always be in the same format, the only unknown is the ordering of the columns (which I determine based on the header row names). In this approach, how would I insert a name/sku into the parent table only if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: That's the magic of the `on conflict` clause - you insert without checking record existence, and use the clause to tell the db how to process if there is a conflict (based on some unique key - you can use the actual constraint name, or the name of the unique columns). You can specify `do nothing`, or you can specify `do update`. This behavior is called `upsert` and was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.5. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT